# Insert/embed Button on image Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a javascript snip which can insert button to all image in page(like google image) when hover the image.

I already build some code but I don't know why button no show up.

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
        var btnGrab = document.getElementById('btn-images-toGrab');
        var t = event.target.offsetTop;
        var l = event.target.offsetLeft;
        var w_center = event.target.offsetWidth / 2 + l;
        btnGrab.style = 'top:'+ t +'px; left:'+ w_center +'px;';
        btnGrab.style.display = 'inline-block'
    });
}
```

Help me I don't know how to append or add button to `img`.
Thanks.

Comment: `<img>` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element) meaning it cannot have child. If you want to do something when user click the image look [`addEventListener("click", Fn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Add_a_simple_listener) and [`clickEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

Comment: the display style should be 'absolute'

Comment: well, i meant the **position** should be _absolute_ [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLqKJR](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLqKJR)

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the for loop have you tried appending the button to the image?

imgs[i].appendChild(btnGrab)

Comment: no work, i think im wrong to build button(btn-images-toGrab).Can u help me script button for img?

Comment: `<img>` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element) meaning it cannot have child. So `appendChild` cannot work here

Comment: jonatjano is right. What you should do is use div to wrap image and button and on div mouseenter show button

Comment: mr Lazar Nikolic can u help me to warp image with div?
what should i do

sorry for my bad english

Comment: could you please share your code on codepen or something similar?

Comment: Lazar Nikolic, can i know your email?
i cant build the script to codepen, i learn to make extension for chrome.

Comment: this from Chris  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLqKJR, this code can show up button but when i use to google image, th button show random position. 
im build for extension chrome, i can share the file if u want

Answer (score 0):

if you change

```
btnGrab.style = 'top:'+ t +'px; left:'+ w_center +'px;';
```

to

```
btnGrab.style = 'position:absolute;top:'+ t +'px; left:'+ w_center +'px;';
```

and the button to the html

```
<button id="btn-images-toGrab" style="display:none;">Click me</button>
```

you should be fine

Comment: i use this script for build extension chrome. when i use var button = document.createElement('button'); button.setAttribute("id", "btn-images-grab"); , button not show up. if i use insertAdjacentHTML can show up but the button position change

Comment: hi sir Crisim, i use absolute, the position button still random no showing up in image.

Comment: sorry, i can't help you. i didn't ever build a chrome extension. i didn't notice the tag earlier..